# no visible @interface for "UITableView" declares the selector "cellForRowAtIndexPath:"

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am new in `IOS6` dev. I got a problem with `UITableView`. My code below is to display Check Mark at the end of the row selected. But I received an error like "no visible **@interface** for `UITableView` declares the selector `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`". `UITableView` has `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, but tableView cannot
show it. I don't know why. Please help.

Below is the code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];   -----error line
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
  }
```

The problem is "tableView" cannot recognize all the methods under UITableView. Some it knows such as "numberOfRowsInSection". I cannot figure out why.

Comment: indexPath.row instead of indexPath inside the error line..

Comment: How did you create the instance of `UITableView`?

Comment: @lakesh That's a blunder

Comment: Yup. That is but thats off topic so I ignored it :P

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you posted. Is that an actual copy and paste of your code? Usually this kind of error is because of a spelling problem.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. This code is not copy and paste. I made serveral tests and each time I got the same error. I've checked the spelling and they are fine.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>The TableView itself does not implement this selector.
The full selector for this method is</strike>

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and is from the protocol for the delegate. Your delegate (e.g. the viewController) has to implement this method. It is not recommended (and not easily possible) to get the cell object from the table.

Instead, change the underlying data and redraw your table with

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: here sais that it should http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: +1 because this addresses a subtle point that you definitely should change the underlying model, and that `tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` should set the checkmark according to the data in that model. Very important. But, -1 because I disagree that reloading the whole table. Bad UX. At most, `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`. The key issue, though, is that the OP's code is fine. His immediate problem is not with this method. It rests elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not in the code sample you include. Your problem rests elsewhere. We can't diagnose the problem on the basis of this one snippet. You'll have to share a more complete code sample with us.

---

Unrelated to your question, there is a subtle issue in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. You should not just be updating the `cellAccessoryType` here. You really should be updating your model that backs your UI. This would be critical if the table had more rows than were visible at any given moment in time.

To illustrate the idea, let's assume your model was an array of objects with two properties, the `title` of the cell and whether the cell was `selected` or not.

Thus, your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` might look like:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    RowData *rowObject = self.objects[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = rowObject.title;

    if (rowObject.isSelected)
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    else
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    return cell;
}
```

And your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` might look like:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    RowData *rowObject = self.objects[indexPath.row];
    rowObject.selected = !rowObject.isSelected;

    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

Again, your compiler warning/error is undoubtedly stems from some other problem in your source code, as your original code snippet is syntactically correct. I'm just trying to correct a different flaw in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. In MVC programming, you really want to make sure you're updating your model (and then updating your view), not just updating the view.

But, to be clear, if you don't correct the error that is causing your current compiler warning/error, you'll probably just get another warning regardless of what you put into `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. You have to identify why the compiler is balking at your current code.

Comment: Thanks guys. The problem solved by updated the xcode from 4.6.2 to 4.6.3. It is very strange and I don't know why it works. Just strange.